# How to use Library on Github in IOS?

Tags: ios, facebook, github

I'm developing an app, and there is a function that allow user to share my app on Facebook. Therefore I used this library: [Simple-Share for iOS](https://github.com/x2on/simple-share-ios/). I follow their instruction and I can run their example.

But the problem is I want to used it in my project but I dont know how to do. In their instruction they said that -> "Then run ./build.sh and drop the libsimple-share.a file into your Xcode project. Copy the include folder also to your project and set the "Header Search Path" to this folder."

I copied their "libsimple-share.a" file already but I dont know what they mean to include their folder and set "Header Search Path".
Please help me!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

Following are the steps to add header search path for external 3rd party libraries :

```
Select build settings of project
Select Header Search Paths property from settings
Add header directory, dont forget last /and surrounding quotes
```

Comment: You save my whole day. Thanks in advance